# Creating a video effect template

Tags: video, after-effects, video-editor, adobe

A friend of mine has a Gopro and something happened to the lens last weekend. We didn't realise that it was damaged and now we have a bunch of videos of our camping trip with a circular smudge looking thing in the centre of the screen.

The smudge gives the centre of the picture a blur.

Is there a way that I can set up a template so that I can make some changes to just the section that it is damaged in an attempt to correct the blur. Once I have found the best settings I would be able to reuse the template for all of the videos. I'm sure it won't fix it perfectly but I would like to try it.

If anyone can point me in the right direction (a link or tutorial) that would be great. I have the Adobe programs so preferably using those

Im a noob

Thanks for you time

Comment: Do you just want to correct the smudge/blur in the original files, or do you want to create an edited video with the original files?

Comment: out of interest, how are you correcting the blur?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your issue, it sounds as if you could duplicate the video to a second layer, apply whatever correction is needed to that layer, and reveal the layer where needed using a soft circular matte.